# Data from backend not visible in html page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular 8 application. And I have a service for retrieving courses from a api call.

So the service method looks like this:

```
  loadCourseById(courseId: number) {
       return this.http.get<Course>(`/api/courses/${courseId}`)
            .pipe(
              shareReplay()
            );
    }
```

and the component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

  course$: Observable<Course>;


  lessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private courseService: CoursesService) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const courseId =  parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('courseId'));

    this.course$ = this.courseService.loadCourseById(courseId);

    console.log(courseId);

  }
}
```

and template looks like this:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf = "(course$ | async) as course">

    <div class="course">

      <h2>{{course?.description}}</h2>

      <img class="course-thumbnail" [src]="course?.iconUrl">

      <table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z7">

        <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        </thead>

      </table>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

So I have checked the api call. And I see in the console.log that I get the correct data back.

But in the html page it is empty so no content is visible.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're miss a small change in your code

remove this pipe from your service

```
.pipe(shareReplay());
```

and for your template there are 2 possible change to proceed:

1 - remove () inside your **ngIf** statement => *ngIf="course$ | async as course"

```
<h2>{{course.description}}</h2>
<img class="course-thumbnail" [src]="course.iconUrl">
....
```

2 - your **ngIf** statement will look like this => *ngIf="course$ | async"

```
<h2>{{(course$ | async)?.description}}</h2>
<img class="course-thumbnail" [src]="(course$ | async)?.iconUrl">
....
```

I hope that is helpfull